# TypeError at /follow/4 follow() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_id'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm creating a follow/unfollow button where a user clicks on the button and follows the other user if they are not already following the user.

I am getting a TypeError with the below code;

MODESL.PY

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    following = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self", blank=True, related_name="followers", symmetrical=False
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)
```

URL.PY

```
path("profile/<int:user_id>", views.profile, name="profile"),
path("follow/<int:user_id>", views.follow, name="follow"),
```

PROFILE.HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <b> following : </b>
    <p class="text-muted"> {{ profile.following.count }} </p>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b> followers : </b>
    <p class="text-muted"> {{ profile.followers.count }} </p>
</div>

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if user in profile.following.all %}
        <a href="{% url 'follow' user.id  %}" class="btn btn-primary">Unfollow</a>
    {% else %}
        <a  href="{% url 'follow' user.id  %}" class="btn btn-primary"> Follow </a>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Message</button>    
    <p class="text-muted"> please, login to follow </p>
{% endif %}
```

VIEWS.PY

```
def profile(request, user_id):
    profile = User.objects.get(pk = user_id)  
    context = {
        "profile": profile,
    }
    return render(request, "network/profile.html", context)

def follow(request, user_id):
    authorObj = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    currentUserObj = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
    following = authorObj.following.all()

    if user_id != currentUserObj.pk:
        if currentUserObj in following:
            authorObj.following.remove(currentUserObj)
        else:
            authorObj.following.add(currentUserObj)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
```

I suspect the error is coming from the views

`def follow(request, user_id):`

searching on the template for the argument 'user_id which I've checked and the following user.id should resolve the issue but still I'm getting the same error

```
``{% if user in profile.following.all %}
        <a href="{% url 'follow' user.id  %}" class="btn btn-primary">Unfollow</a>
    {% else %}
        <a  href="{% url 'follow' user.id  %}" class="btn btn-primary"> Follow </a>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}``
```

Comment: To me shown code looks fine. Try searching other `follow` implementation in your codebase. And add full error traceback to your question.

Comment: Yes, @IvanStarostin That is what caused the error, thank you. I thought I commented out all my previous trials but I didn't